# Need help identifying this signature chop? wondering about meaning, age, history? (Characters identified: 彝齋)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

I have this beautiful silk wall screen with lilies, and would love to know more about it. I cannot can't find any information. Can anyone help identify the chop stamp please? wondering about meaning, age, history?

Thank you.

[image]